# Picasso.Не подгружает drawable из Resources

Tags: java, android, picasso

В эмуляторе AndroidStudio все подгружается и прекрасно работает, а на реально устройстве(galaxy s 6 edge - в данном случае) подгружается только второй case (case 1) остальные не подгружаются.Может это связано с размером файлов? может нужно прописать какие то разрешения для файлов больше 500кб? или что то в этом роде?

```
public class PortfolioFullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView fullScreenImage;
    PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.portfolio_page_activity);

        fullScreenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_full_screen);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);



        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.social_trading)

                       .resize(1080,1080)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            case 1:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.nordex)
                        .resize(1400,1287)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            case 2:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.technolite)
                        .resize(1080,2341)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            case 3:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.sia_studio)
                        .resize(1920,2136)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            case 4:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.vavilon)
                        .resize(1080,1928)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            case 5:
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.global_solution)
                        .resize(1080,1224)
                        .into(fullScreenImage);
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(PortfolioFullScreenActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(fullScreenImage);
    }
}
```

### Layout.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.PortfolioFullScreenActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_full_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### UPD:

Есть еще одна особенность, после переустановки apk любая пикча которую открываешь первой отображается, а остальные нет, кроме case 1: он всегда отображается.

Comment: А что означает не подгружаются? отображается как пустота?

Comment: @xAqweRx отображается как пустота.

Comment: А что говорит консоль? NullPointerException7

Comment: Для интереса, попробуй перенести какой-то из вариантов в папку drawable

Comment: @xAqweRx вы видимо не правильно поняли, они перестают отображаться уже на реальном устроцстве, в эмуляторе все прекрасно работает

Comment: @xAqweRx, они и так в папке drawable лежат все

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40091/discussion-between-xaqwerx-and-newakkoff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего размеры превышают  лимит. Максимально допустимые размеры зависят от устройства и их можно узнать при помощи OpenGL:

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

Comment: @new Нет, на эмуляторе подобных ограничений не должно быть

Comment: есть еще одна особенность, после переустановки apk любая пикча которую открываешь первой отображается, а остальные нет, кроме `case 1:` он всегда отображается

Comment: @new Не забывайте про ограничение памяти на приложение. Скорее всего, в вашем случае, первая картинка потребляет большую часть этой памяти. Таким образом, вторая уже не может отобразится. В официальной документации есть немного информации на [эту](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) тему.

Comment: да, видимо проблема в это, решил просто, фотошопом и пересохранением в меньшем размере.Спасибо!